# Error al configurar una Toolbar en Android con Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

buen día, espero se encuentren bien.

Bueno, tengo una pequeña duda, resulta que estoy haciendo un curso de desarrollo de Android con Kotlin, pero es algo viejo, por lo que creo, hay varios métodos que no son los mismos hoy en día, por lo que me gustaría que me ayudaran, ya que no entiendo qué pasa en este error, les dejo una captura de pantalla tanto del curso, como de mi código, a ver si pueden orientarme un poco con esto, de antemano muchas gracias y que tengan un excelente día.[Código[image: ][1]]

Comment: Hola amigo, recuerda si es posible agregar el código como texto ya que en ocasiones algunos miembros de la comunidad no pueden visualizar bien las imágenes, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error es porque importaste el `Toolbar` nativo de android en vez de el de la librería de compatibilidad. Simplemente debes reemplazar esta línea

```
import android.widget.Toolbar
```

por esta

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Y sobre el curso de android no sé cual estés haciendo pero lo más recomendable es hacer el [curso oficial](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course) porque siempre lo mantendrán actualizado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu curso posiblemente no este actualizado, de hecho ve en la barra de estatus de Android Studio el mensaje:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is android.widget.Toolbar but
> androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar? was expected

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto indica que se espera que uses el import para la clase `Toolbar` :

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```